# Oracle sql a column having number datatype using BETWEEN

Tags: sql, oracle

Guys  i have table which has column **st_date** containing dates with datatype number and the values would be like this **20101201 i.e (01-DEC-2010)** .

if i write a select query using between clause for the dates lying between the bounds , my question is whether to use between or less or greater than operator, which is performance efficient.

```
 select id, sum(duration), sum(hit_count) 
 from A 
 where st_date between 20101101 AND 20101130 
 group by id
```

The table has millions of records partitioned by st_date.Is above one better than or the below one.

```
 select id, sum(duration), sum(hit_count) 
 from A 
 where st_date >= 20101101 AND st_date < 20101130 
 group by id
```

kindly let me know your answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second one is more performant because it selects less data :)

Internally, `between` is rewritten as >= and <=. You can see it in the predicate information part of the execution plan.

```
explain plan for select * from t1 where n between 100 and 200;

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("N">=100 AND "N"<=200)
```

Also, while we are at it:

Don't store dates as numbers.

Oracle knows that the difference between `date '2010-12-31' and date '2011-01-01'` is 1 day.
Oracle also knows that there the difference between 20101231 and 20110101 is 8870.

Think about what that does to cardinality estimates.

Answer (score 4):

`BETWEEN` is Inclusive. that means `>=` lower AND `<=` upper.

So your examples are not quite the same.  Assuming you fix, then they will generate the same query plan.

Use of `BETWEEN` is somewhat clearer.

Answer (score 1):

As Mitch Wheat stated in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623651/oracle-sql-a-column-having-number-datatype-using-between/4623674#4623674), after having fixed the 3rd line of your second query as

```
where st_date >= 20101101 AND st_date <= 20101130
```

then your two queries will generate the same results. There won't be any differences in terms of *completion time* either.

I personally use [`BETWEEN`](http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-BETWEEN.asp) whenever I need to define time/date intervals.